# How to configure kibana for multiple nodes in the same cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a ES cluster with three nodes, and the master will produce through election. So I want to know how to make Kibana listen to the cluster rather than only for one node like using elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:8200". Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible right now, there's an open issue about it: [#214](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/214) (opened for 2+ years)

Kibana 4 can currently only reverse-proxy a single ES host. You don't necessarily need to reference a master node. You could create a small client node (with `master: false` and `data: false`), add it to your cluster and configure Kibana to point at it. That way you get load-balancing for free and don't need to care if the master changes or goes down.

**UPDATE**

[As of Kibana 6.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.6/release-highlights-6.6.0.html#_support_for_multiple_elasticsearch_nodes), it is possible to provide [multiple ES hosts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/production.html#high-availability)

Comment: is it still not available? I don't find any doc related to this.

Comment: @Gibbs Good point, it's possible now. I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes, But it connects to the first active node in the list. As mentioned there, we need to dedicate a tribe node otherwise. Thanks Val.

Comment: @Gibbs That's not what it says, Kibana will add all specified nodes to its pool and if one becomes unavailable it will jump to the another one. Nowhere is mentioned anything about tribe nodes (which are deprecated by the way)

Comment: Thanks for your time and precious explanations Val.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana suggests to "run an Elasticsearch Coordinating only node on the same machine as Kibana". [Load Balancing Across Multiple Elasticsearch Nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.6/production.html#load-balancing) describes the details about how to configure the ElasticSearch Coordinating node for Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse-proxy/load-balancer but it gets messy. A simpler solution will be to install Elasticsearch with coordinating-only node configuration on same machine/VM/instance as Kibana with following configurations:
1. Add these lines to elasticsearch.yml for coordinating-only node.

```
node.master: false 
node.data: false 
node.ingest: false
```

2. Update the discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts to add the new node (coordinating-only). In your case, there will be 4 hosts.
3. refer to localhost: in kibana dashboard configuration file.

Hope this helps.